# Для чего нужна "@" в location'е (NGINX)?

Tags: nginx, docker, микросервисы

Объясните пожалуйста, для чего применяется символ `@` внутри конфигурационного файла nginx при указании пути и о чем говорит данный кусок кода:

```
location @web {
  proxy_pass http://web:3000;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Префикс “@” задаёт именованный location. Такой location не
>   используется при обычной обработке запросов, а предназначен только для
>   перенаправления в него запросов. Такие location’ы не могут быть
>   вложенными и не могут содержать вложенные location’ы.

[Документация](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)